# FF Javascript Styling issue with text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

The idea is that there is a "hidden" text box with no background so it sits nicely on the background.

When the text box is clicked on it makes the value blank and changes the text to black.

This works in Chrome and IE but not in Firefox,

```html
<input id="emailSubscribe" name="email" type="text" value="Subscribe for updates, Just enter your email Address"></input>
```

```js
 $("#emailSubscribe").focus(function(){
    if($("#emailSubscribe").val() == "Subscribe for updates, Just enter your email Address"){
        $("#emailSubscribe").val("")
        $("#emailSubscribe").css("color", "black");
        $("#buttonBar").fadeIn(700);
    }
    });
```

Comment: fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fhsmJ/2/
What is not working? is it not clearing the input box, is it not changing color? Works fine on my machine ;)

Comment: how far back should your browser support be? you might want to think about using the `placeholder` attribute. Also, your input needs to be self closing, ie not `<input></input` but `<input />`

Comment: It seems to work in jsfiddle too but on [link]http://onlinewatermarks.com/anchorpoint/index.php[link] It doesn't work in firefox, even though it's running the same code

Comment: css element works fine for eveybrowser ,actually whats your problem

Comment: @KunalVashist It's working on FF for you?

Comment: @obkso I have seen your website now. It is an UI issue. That's why the text field is not showing up. No error in jQuery. try disabling the `padding:40px;` of `input[type="text"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the semicolon(;)

Your `$("#emailSubscribe").val("")` should be `$("#emailSubscribe").val("");`

Comment: Yeah it should oops! But it still doesn't work.

Comment: check out clearing your browser cache CTRL+Shift+Del. JavaScripts are sometimes cached. I dont see any errors in your code.

Comment: I have seen your website now. It is an UI issue. That's why the text field is not showing up. No error in jQuery. try disabling the `padding:40px;` of `input[type="text"]`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why yours doesn't but this works for me in FF.

http://jsfiddle.net/5CtMc/